# Are these two instancetype initialization methods equal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, instancetype

I was wondering are these two equal:

A single parentheses inside the if statement:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    
    if (self = [super init]) {
        
        // ...
    }
    
    return self;
}
```

Double parentheses inside the if statement:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        
        // ...
    }
    
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,...... as it only depends on the the expression being compared no matter how many parentheses exists (that should be even)

**Parentheses** help compiler understand the expressions with prioritization , `if` statement in objective c needs at least one `()` while adding more will work also but it's useless

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equal.

`self` is getting the reference that it needs to store after `[super init]` call. Both of these do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, in that they mean the same thing and produce the same code, however the compiler will behave a little differently.

In C like languages an easy typing mistake that is visually hard to spot is to enter `=`, that is *assignment*, when `==`, that is `equality`, is intended. This error can produce very different results and hard to spot bugs. E.g.:

```
if (a == b) { ... }
```

tests whether `a` and `b` have the same value and if so the statements in the `if` are executed. However:

```
if (a = b) { ... }
```

assigns the value in `b` to `a` and then executes the statements if the value of `a` and `b` (they have the same value due to the assignment) is non-zero. Clearly the two behaviours are quite different.

To help out if the compiler sees a single `=` in an `if` it will issue a warning so the programmer is alerted to the possibility of a typo. The warning will be omitted if double parentheses are used:

```
if ((a = b)) { ... }
```

which is why you'll see this pattern in code. HTH